# Return 2 IntegerFields from a model

Tags: django, django-models

I have written the following model, which takes in 2 integers, i.e. x-coordinate and y-coordinate. I want the name of the model to be (x,y) for which I have added the **str**(self) function.

```
class Point(models.Model):
    xpoint = models.IntegerField()
    ypoint = models.IntegerField()
    def __str__(self):
        return (self.xpoint + " , " + self.ypoint)
```

Am I doing it correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No - you will get an error when trying to concatenate integers with strings. Do this instead using [`str.format()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format):

```
def __str__(self):
    return '{} , {}'.format(self.xpoint, self.ypoint)
```